# Django's FileField (or ImageField) on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, blobstore, django-storage

GAE doesn't allow read/write to file system, which is what Django's FileField (or ImageField) is using (via the FileSystemStorage class).

I was thinking implementing a custom Django storage, but the GAE blobstore seems to be completely incompatible with the Django requirements. Specifically, GAE blobstore assume direct upload from client to store, while Django custom storage need to implement a _save(name, content) method.

As far as I can see no one refer to this missing implementation. There are some custom storage projects out there (most notably: django-storages on BitBucket), with implementations for S3, Windows Azure, dozens of other backend, but nothing for Google.

What direction should I take to have a FileField in my model, hosted on Google App Engine?

To clarify:
- I'm using to stocked, trunk, the one that uses Google Cloud SQL Django that comes with Google SDK - I'm not using Django nonrel.
- I've followed the [Django guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) from Google documentation.

Answer (score 1):

blobstore now support writing files feature. see
[writing file to the blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). Therefore it is possible to implement the `_save(name, content)` with blobstore now.

Another way is using cloud storage. it provide more features such as listdir, open, delete than blobstore.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/